# SQL bug with decimals when substract money?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, payment, currency

I am storing user money with decimal(12,3).When I charge user for some amount of money it works but when I charge it with 0, sometimes query return false,sometimes return true.false and true doesn't depend on anything ,I think it is sql bug.My query is like below:

```
update `user_account`
set `total_money` = `total_money` - ?
where `user_id` = ?
    and `total_money` >= ?
order by `total_money` desc LIMIT 1
```

then I bind params like this `$charge_amount,$user_id,$charge_amount)`

Why it return random false and true when `$charge_amount` is 0.I know being `$charge_amount` 0 is not make sense but this process will be depend on process.System will calculate amount then will charge user.If it `return false` it will insert that your payment failed. I know that I can fix it with php by checking amount is 0 just return true,but I want to learn reason that why it is random and is that best way to store money,and substract?All of return false's caused by affected,if it is affected it return true,if it is not it return false.

**Brief Explanation**

When I charge 0 it says sometimes not affected,sometimes affected

Comment: Please show us the exact values where the query is givng you unexpected behavior.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if $charge_amount is 0 , it always return random true|false , and it doesn't depend on `total_money` that user has

Comment: If `mysqi_execute()` returns `false` it means there was an error, you should print `mysqli_error($conn)` to see the reason.

Comment: @Barmar All of return false's caused by affected,if it is affected it return true,if it is not it return false

Comment: @Barmar my problem is if I charge 0 it says sometimes not affected,sometimes affected

Comment: If the code that is evaluating success is giving you trouble, it might be a good idea to add the code that is evaluating success. A rule of thumb is: if you expect something to be a mysql bug, it is in 95% of cases a bug in your code. One suspect for a bug in your code would be that you expect the `number of affected rows` to be > 0 for a row that just changes a value by 0.

Comment: Post your actual code. I don't understand where you say it's returning `false`.